# How to execute script as bash using "at"?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, at-job

It was a pain to google solutions for my problem since it is using application "at" :)
So the thing is, I am trying to run long runnng operation (I know that I could add some specific entry to cron, but I am still learning new stuff") and I decided to use "at" application.
The thing is that it does not run properly and as I believe it is because at runs applications as shell intead of bash by default.

```
echo "./home/user/test.sh" | at now
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 5 at Sun Apr 17 12:34:00 2022
```

I've also tried suggestion from other tread that I've found on SOF and tried to create .bash script extensions for my script/s
So my question is - how to make "at" run scripts as bash instead of shell?

Comment: See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86048). Or try `echo "bash ./home/user/test.sh"` if you're in a hurry.

Comment: Questions about using UNIX systems belong on [unix.se]; Stack Overflow is only for questions about _writing software_.

Comment: This does not work for me (using ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

1 .

> how to make "at" run scripts as bash instead of shell

```
echo '/bin/bash /home/user/test.sh' | at now
```

2 .

However your problem might be simpler:

You must add `./` before the name of a program/script run from a **relative path**, which protects you from accidentally running a program from a local directory.
The dot represents the current directory and it literally tells your shell: "*from current directory run this program*".

When you specify the **absolute path** to your executable, you do not prefix it with `./`, because it is 1. invalid, as that executable is not in your current directory 2. needless, as by using the absolute path you already confirm that it is not a mistake and you know what you are doing.

So this should be enough:

```
echo '/home/user/test.sh' | at now
```

3 .

To state what shell (interpreter) should run your script, simply add a **shebang** as its first line:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Your script's extension does not matter, be it `.sh`, `.bash` or even no extension at all.

Comment: Thank you, it works! It still says that it will run using /bin/sh but finally my scripts run!:)